# Can we use Scanner(System.in).nextInt() in java?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Can this statement be used in Java:

```
int  a = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
```

If it can, can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: You’ll have to use `new` to create a `Scanner` object, but yes. Can you add some more code and context?

Comment: Have you, I dunno, tried running it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it this way also, but you are not assigning the `Scanner` object to any reference variable. So if you want to read any input again you would need to create another `Scanner` object.

```
int a = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
```

The best approach is to create a `Scanner` object and store it in a reference variable.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Answer (score 2):

`Scanner` is a class and `nextInt()` isn't static method
so,you must use `new` keyword to make `Scanner` object, and then you can use that method

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the following code would work:

```
System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
int k = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
System.out.println(k);
```

Why? You are declaring an int (k). You are setting it's value equal to a new instance of the Scanner object that we are creating which will store the int primitive that we choose to enter. So the type is compatible. IF you attempted to use the Scanner.next() method used for strings, or the Scanner.nextFloat() method, they would not be compatable. Since we will be storing an integer however, there is no compilation error with this statement.

BUT just because you can do something in Java doesn't mean that you should. It is a better practice to first create a Scanner object, and then create the int variable:

```
System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
int k = reader.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

This statement is not right. You have to create an object of class `Scanner` by using the `new` operator as shown below.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int val = sc.nextInt();
```

Comment: But i seen someone on internet doing this

Comment: @Pratikkataria With or without `new`? The code snippet would work with `new`, but the object would be garbage collected after reading one input.

Comment: @Steephen a = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt(); then what is the object of this statement

Comment: @Pratikkataria  `new Scanner(System.in)` does create a temporary object of Scanner with out any name.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is not correct. It needs to be the following:

```
int value = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
```

Only do this if you are not planning to use the `Scanner` object again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be used.

Assigning it to a Scanner object and calling a function is popular choice and also it increases readability.

It is important to assign it to a Scanner object when you want to use it more than once.

Example:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

int sum = 0, count = 0;

while (sc.hasNextInt())
{
    int num = sc.nextInt();
    sum += num;
    count++;
}
```

here you are using the same object more than once.

But if you are going to do something like this,

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

int num = sc.nextInt();

System.out.println("num " + num);
```

here you are using the object only once.

It is not really important to assign it to object and call the function. You can simply do this

```
System.out.println("num" + new Scanner(System.in).nextInt());
```